# Use react prop or html element in const declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've created a `Button` component which is applying all sorts of styling and classes based on the passed props. I would like to also be able to specify another `component` in the props such as a `Link` from `react-router`. Nesting causes al sort of issues (clicking on padding does not work etc).

To do this I would accept a `component` prop which would allow this however when this prop is not set I would like to use the default html `<button>` element.

I often use the `||` when doing something similar with custom components but I can't seem to get it to work with a default html element.

```
class Button extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        const {
            size,
            width,
            variation,
            disabled,
            loading,
            position,
            children,
            className,
            component,
            ...otherProps
        } = this.props;

        // Here lies the problem, "button" is not defined here, how to use the default html element while not loosing props specified below?
        const Button = component || button; 

        return (
            <Button
                className={classnames(
                    "BUTTON",
                    {
                        [`BUTTON-size--${size}`]: size,
                        [`BUTTON-width--${width}`]: width,
                        [`BUTTON-variation--${variation}`]: variation,
                        [`BUTTON-position--${position}`]: position,
                        "BUTTON-state--disabled": disabled,
                        "BUTTON-state--loading": loading
                    },
                    className
                )}
                disabled={disabled || loading}
                {...otherProps}
            >
                {children}
            </Button>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: try this `const Button = component || <input type="button" />;`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an anonymous component

Try doing

```
const Button = component || (props) => <button {...props}/>
```

Or (as other here said)

```
const Button = component || (props) => <input type="button" {...props}/>
```

Or as @Joshua Underwood suggested

```
const Button = component || 'button'
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this have any negative effects on performance that users will notice? I ask this because I read that passing anonymous functions is not good for performance :/

Comment: I honestly would not know, try testing this.
Like you can also use an if statement if you wish, the results may be the same

Comment: additionally, this is the only way I know to implement what you want in the way you want it to

Comment: Hmm, but how could I pass an `a` tag as component then?

Comment: Pass through where?
I made a little jsfiddler here: https://jsfiddle.net/asosnovsky/69z2wepo/92671/
Is this what you mean?

Comment: Is this the right way to use a `a` as component in the custom `Button` component? https://jsfiddle.net/1ctzwzgh/

Comment: It seems to work. I would say that it is correct.
In terms of performance, I can't comment, since I have not ran or seen tests about this.
I do know, that I have seen similar implementation to this in the material-ui-next library, and so far I have seen any performance cost there

Comment: Thanks for this! I've looked at their source code and found the most easy solution!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [`material-ui-next` ButtonBase](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/ButtonBase/ButtonBase.js#L368-L386) component I've noticed a very simplistic approach to this question namely simply doing the following:

```
class Button extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        const {
            size,
            width,
            variation,
            disabled,
            loading,
            position,
            children,
            className,
            component,
            ...otherProps
        } = this.props;

        const Component = component;

        return (
            <Component
                className={classnames(
                    "BUTTON",
                    {
                        [`BUTTON-size--${size}`]: size,
                        [`BUTTON-width--${width}`]: width,
                        [`BUTTON-variation--${variation}`]: variation,
                        [`BUTTON-position--${position}`]: position,
                        "BUTTON-state--disabled": disabled,
                        "BUTTON-state--loading": loading
                    },
                    className
                )}
                disabled={disabled || loading}
                {...otherProps}
            >
                {children}
            </Component>
        );
    }
}

Button.propTypes = {
    component: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.node, PropTypes.oneOf(["a", "button"])]),
    // ... ohter
};

Button.defaultProps = {
    component: "button",
    // ... other
};

export default Button;
```

Notice I'm just using the `component` prop with a default value of `"button"`.

Answer (score 0):

When you nest components inside your Button class you wouldn't access them via props.component, you'd access them as `this.props.children`

Also with your `const Button = component || button;` the `button` portion needs to be a valid react element so do

```
const Button = component || <input type="button">
```

or

```
const Button = component || <button>
```

Comment: This answer is giving no compilation errors but when i try to view it in the browser I get multiple errors `Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Comment: I believe the answer by @asosnovsky is more suited to your needs as mine is incomplete. Once his successfully helps you and you mark it accepted ill remove mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want such a polymorphic component that receives the class of its UI as a parameter, I wouldn't use its class name inside its render method.

```js
function MySpan(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

class Button extends React.Component {    
   render() {
   const {
            name,
            component
        } = this.props;

        return React.createElement(
          component ? eval(component) : 'button',
          this.props,
          `Hello ${name}`
        );       
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Button width="200" component="MySpan" name="Blueish" />,
document.getElementById('span')
);

ReactDOM.render(
<Button width="200" name="Blue" />,
document.getElementById('button')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="span"></div>
  <div id="button"></div>
</body>
```